# vb.net Button with dropdown arrow

Tags: vb.net, button

I want to make something like this.

[image]

It seems like a `dropdown` menu button.

I know how to make it by using the `ContextMenuStrip` and this code

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WorkersButtonStrip.Show(Button1, 0, Button1.Height)
End Sub
```

But then i need to set up two images. One image is `dropdown` arrow centered on right and the second image is "Worker.icon" and that is the part I'm not able to ? .

Do i need to make two buttons or how ? I really stuck. How is this called anyway how can i google this

Comment: Typically you want the base button to behave 2 ways: do something when clicked (a default) or show the menu when the "arrowed" portion is clicked.  The work is already done fr you - search CodeProject - there are perhaps 2 dozen variants

Comment: @Plutonix I wanted to open dropdown menu on click. There is no a default or arrowed portion. Its only one no matter where you click it should open you a dropdown menu. I managed to do it with ToolStrip and SplitButton but searching a way with normal button.

Answer (score 1):

Tool Strip < Add splitButton < Set image < Display Type < Image and Text.

Don't forget in options to change "Size to Fit"